# Find the biggest 3 numbers in a vector

Tags: c++, vector, c++builder

I'm trying to make a function to get the 3 biggest numbers in a vector. For example:
Numbers: 1 6 2 5 3 7 4
Result: 5 6 7

I figured I could sort them DESC, get the 3 numbers at the beggining, and after that resort them ASC, but that would be a waste of memory allocation and execution time. I know there is a simpler solution, but I can't figure it out. And another problem is, what if I have only two numbers...

BTW: I use as compiler BorlandC++ 3.1 (I know, very old, but that's what I'll use at the exam..)

Thanks guys.

LE: If anyone wants to know more about what I'm trying to accomplish, you can check the code:

```
#include<fstream.h>
#include<conio.h>

int v[1000], n;
ifstream f("bac.in");

void citire();
void afisare_a();
int ultima_cifra(int nr);
void sortare(int asc);

void main() {
    clrscr();
    citire();
    sortare(2);
    afisare_a();
    getch();
}

void citire() {
    f>>n;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        f>>v[i];
        f.close();
}                            

void afisare_a() {
    for(int i = 0;i < n; i++)
            if(ultima_cifra(v[i]) == 5)
            cout<<v[i]<<" ";
}

int ultima_cifra(int nr) {
    return nr - 10 * ( nr / 10 );
}

void sortare(int asc) {
    int aux, s;
        if(asc == 1)
        do {
            s = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
                if(v[i] > v[i+1]) {
                    aux = v[i];
                    v[i] = v[i+1];
                    v[i+1] = aux;
                    s = 1;
                }
        } while( s == 1);
    else
        do {
            s = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
                if(v[i] < v[i+1]) {
                    aux = v[i];
                    v[i] = v[i+1];
                    v[i+1] = v[i];
                                        s = 1;
                }
                } while(s == 1);
}
```

Citire = Read
Afisare = Display
Ultima Cifra = Last digit of number
Sortare = Bubble Sort

Comment: Why is this tagged bubble-sort?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what kind of exam is that? Even at University, we had access to current compilers. And learning (passing exams) in such ancient technologies doesn’t sound very useful. ;-)

Comment: I'm really curious why you are doing two sorts?

Comment: I've edited the post so you can see why I tagged it with Bubble Sort. And yes, it's a Unversity exam, but Romania still uses paper at its exams instead of PCs... Now that I'm thinking at it after reading the responses, sorting it twice is non-sense.

Answer (score 14):

If you were using a modern compiler, you could use `std::nth_element` to find the top three. As is, you'll have to scan through the array keeping track of the three largest elements seen so far at any given time, and when you get to the end, those will be your answer.

For three elements that's a trivial thing to manage. If you had to do the N largest (or smallest) elements when N might be considerably larger, then you'd almost certainly want to use Hoare's `select` algorithm, just like `std::nth_element` does.

Comment: Best STL, and also the best heuristic for a non-STL solution

Comment: +1 because it uses standard C++ libs, but for the questioner, I don't think he's allowed to use it since Borland 3.1 is early, early 90s I think. :)

Comment: ...the good old days of Turbo C++ (1 version older I believe)

Comment: @nevets1219: There were Turbo C++ 1.0, Borland C++ 2.0, Borland C++ 3.0, then Borland C++ 3.1. To paraphrase an old line, Borland C++ 3.1 was a huge improvement over its predecessors -- and successors.

Comment: Well, I first learned PHP, because I'm a native web developer, and now learning C++ on Borland C++ is a real pain :(

Comment: @BDesign: Yes -- unless you really need to continue using it, you'd almost certainly be better off with one of the newer alternatives that's freely available (e.g., a current build of MinGW or Visual C++ Express).

Comment: nth_element is the fastest algorithm to the general problem x of y.

Answer (score 12):

You could do this without needing to sort at all, it's doable in O(n) time with linear search and 3 variables keeping your 3 largest numbers (or indexes of your largest numbers if this vector won't change).

Comment: This is not great for followup question "find the largest 10000 out of a list of 1000000"

Comment: @Steve true, if it became an arbitrary "find the top x out of y" problem, then my solution would not be a good fit and I would choose to do something like yours. I specifically wanted to answer Bdesign's immediate question for picking a very small subset from (what I assume) is a limited list, without having to go through his vague double sorting.

Comment: The question itself doesn't ask for that, for that kind of followup then of course you would approach it differently. At the moment, there's no exact details on memory or speed requirements.

Comment: It's a comment, not a downvote justification.  @Jerry's solution is the best generic implementation, yours is best *in situ*.

Comment: @Steve, I saw it as well-deserved comment. My solution jumped to my head as being a good fit for the questioner's scope and working with his limitation of using an ancient compiler. I wouldn't say my answer is anywhere near the best - I never do, because I can never be sure someone else will come along and propose something even better.

Comment: It's fairly good even for top x of y. You just need to compare each with the current lowest of x to know whether one of those needs replacing with that value.

Comment: @Paul, in general, the runtime of that would be Omega(ylogx) assuming you use a heap to store the top x.  A better solution is the partitioning algorithm nth_element and then a linear pass, which is Omega(y) time, but unfortunately destroys the array (or needs O(y) additional storage.)

Answer (score 4):

Why not just step through it once and keep track of the 3 highest digits encountered?

EDIT: The range for the input is important in how you want to keep track of the 3 highest digits.

Answer (score 3):

Use `std::partial_sort` to descending sort the first `c` elements that you care about. It will run in linear time for a given number of desired elements (`n log c`) time.

Comment: Partial sort is the easiest to code, but nth_element and then a linear partition stays linear time whereas partial_sort for the "x of y" problem is Omega(ylogx) time.

Comment: @Neil G Both approaches are linear in the number of elements in the container for a particular desired number of highest elements. You're right that `partial_sort` can have a slightly higher `C` in many circumstances, but in practice this probably doesn't matter.

Comment: partial sort has to sort the x elements, so it has the additional log(x) factor.  Consider the limiting case where x=y, the partial sort runs in xlogx time where was the nth_element solution runs in x time.   However, I was wrong earlier and the runtime of the partial sort solution is probably Omega(y + xlogx), so it's the same as the nth element solution if x is independent of y.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't use std::nth_element write your own selection function.

You can read about them here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm#Selecting_k_smallest_or_largest_elements

Answer (score 1):

Sort them normally and then iterate from the back using `rbegin()`, for as many as you wish to extract (no further than `rend()` of course).

`sort` will happen in  place whether ASC or DESC by the way, so memory is not an issue since your container element is an `int`, thus has no encapsulated memory of its own to manage.

Answer (score 1):

Yes sorting is good. A especially for long or variable length lists.

Why are you sorting it twice, though? The second sort might actually be very inefficient (depends on the algorithm in use). A reverse would be quicker, but why even do that? If you want them in ascending order at the end, then sort them into ascending order first ( and fetch the numbers from the end)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the choice between scanning the vector for the three largest elements or sorting it (either using sort in a vector or by copying it into an implicitly sorted container like a set).

Answer (score 0):

If you can control the array filling maybe you could add the numbers ordered and then choose the first 3 (ie), otherwise you can use a binary tree to perform the search or just use a linear search as birryree says...

Answer (score 0):

Thank @nevets1219 for pointing out that the code below only deals with positive numbers.

I haven't tested this code enough, but it's a start:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> nums;
    nums.push_back(1);
    nums.push_back(6);
    nums.push_back(2);
    nums.push_back(5);
    nums.push_back(3);
    nums.push_back(7);
    nums.push_back(4);

    int first = 0;
    int second = 0;
    int third = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++)
    {
        if (nums.at(i) > first)
        {
            third = second;
            second = first;            
            first = nums.at(i);
        }
        else if (nums.at(i) > second)
        {
            third = second;
            second = nums.at(i);
        }
        else if (nums.at(i) > third)
        {
            third = nums.at(i);
        }
        std::cout << "1st: " << first << " 2nd: " << second << " 3rd: " << third << std::endl;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You may want to include a note saying that this takes only positive non-zero integers. If zero and negative numbers were allowed then additional logic will be needed. Also you need to take the cout out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution finds the three largest numbers in O(n) and preserves their relative order:

```
std::vector<int>::iterator p = std::max_element(vec.begin(), vec.end());
int x = *p;
*p = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();

std::vector<int>::iterator q = std::max_element(vec.begin(), vec.end());
int y = *q;
*q = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();

int z = *std::max_element(vec.begin(), vec.end());

*q = y;   // restore original value
*p = x;   // restore original value
```

Answer (score 0):

A general solution for the top `N` elements of a vector:

1. Create an array or vector `topElements` of length `N` for your top `N` elements.
2. Initialise each element of `topElements` to the value of your first element in your vector.
3. Select the next element in the vector, or finish if no elements are left.
4. If the selected element is greater than `topElements[0]`, replace `topElements[0]` with the value of the element. Otherwise, go to 3.
5. Starting with `i` = 0, swap `topElements[i]` with `topElements[i + 1]` if `topElements[i]` is greater than `topElements[i + 1]`.
6. While `i` is less than `N`, increment `i` and go to 5.
7. Go to 3.

This should result in `topElements` containing your top `N` elements in reverse order of value - that is, the largest value is in `topElements[N - 1]`.